# triggering js after ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a page containing all the usual elements (html/php, css, js) and from within it I call (using a form) a page via ajax. All that works just fine and I'm happy with that...EXCEPT it's somehow not completing!

The ajax call is:

```
$( ".view_button" ).click(function( event ) {
    $( "#reportframe" ).html( "Loading...");
    var geturl = $( "#holder" ).attr("action");
    $.ajax({
        url: geturl,
        type: 'get',
        dataType: 'html',
        async: false,
        data: $('#holder').serialize()
    })
    .done(function(html) {
        $( "#reportframe" ).html(html);
        alert("Loaded!");
    });
});
```

`.view_button` is the form's submit button, `#holder` is the form id and `#reportframe` is div into which the page is loaded. The reason `geturl` is set is because depending on the options selected in the form it will change the 'action' attribute of the form to get a different page.

There are two things that I can't seem to resolve:

1. The first time the page is loaded via ajax the 'alert' does not show and most jquery elements do not work. HOWEVER, the second (and subsequent) time the page is loaded via ajax the 'alert' pops up on completion and SOME of the jquery elements work!
2. Getting ALL jquery to work in the loaded page! Specifically there's a tool we load called 'tooltipster' - this clearly doesn't get added in because console says 'tooltipster is not a function', even though the js file is called and loaded.

All js/jquery code and files are called at the end of the loaded page.

One more thing - I can't seem to grab `data` to display it even though it clearly gets transmitted in the ajax. Any ideas?

Any insights VERY gratefully received!!

Comment: Just to add, the called page works perfectly when loaded as a separate page in its own right, so I know everything actually works in it.

Comment: `.view_button is the form's submit button` this could be your issue. Try hooking to the `submit` event of the `form` instead and call `preventDefault()` to stop the standard form submission.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I will try that...I'll try anything! Do you think this will change anything though? Because it does submit and the button IS the `submit` input type. Thanks.

Comment: That will definitely fix your problem then. You should either make the AJAX request OR submit the form, not both. You should also remove `async: false` as it's terrible practice.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan OK thanks. Will redo this for submit and let you know. :)

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan if I do `$( ".view_button" ).click(function() { $("#holder").submit(); });` then the form submits, but obviously it's the same as a normal submit - the new page loads and replaces the form. BUT if I do `$( ".view_button" ).click(function() { $("#holder").submit(function(event) { event.preventDefault(); }); });` then nothing happens at all. Basically, if I give the submit a function then it doesn't work..aargh!

Comment: Your second logic is right, but you need to remove the `click()` handler, and only assign the `submit()` handler

Comment: I added an answer with an example for you

Answer (score 0):

If the `.view_button` element is a submit button then the `form` will be submit. This means that JS code will stop execution and the page will be transferred. This in turn means that your AJAX call will not be made, or will be aborted before it completes.

To fix this, hook your code to the `submit` event of the form and call `preventDefault()` on the provided event to stop the standard submission, like this:

```
$("#holder").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $("#reportframe").html('Loading...');

    $.ajax({
        url: $(this).prop('action'),
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'html',
        data: $(this).serialize()
    }).done(function(html) {
        $('#reportframe').html(html);
    });
});
```

Note I removed `async: false` as it's considered very bad practice, to the point where the browser will warn you not to use it in the console.

Also, as you're using this AJAX request to load remote HTML in to an element you could replace the `$.ajax` call with `load()` instead:

```
$("#holder").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();    
    $("#reportframe").html('Loading...').load($(this).prop('action'), $(this).serialize());
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this. The issue I have is that the submit doesn't work at all once something is placed inside its function. So if I have just `$("#holder").submit(); then the form submits as soon as it's loaded, but if it has anything else in it then it just does nothing! I've been trying everything I can think of to no avail. :(

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean. `$("#holder").submit()` raises the submit event as if you actually clicked a button to send the form. Using `$("#holder").submit(fn)` is a submit event handler which runs the code within the function when the form is submit.

Comment: 1. If I just have `$("#holder").submit()` then when the page loads this is automatically triggered once the page has finished loading.
2. If I have `$("#holder").submit(fn)` then even if I press the submit button nothing happens.
1. SHOULDN'T happen, 2. SHOULD happen!

Comment: Ok, well 2. should be happening with the above code, just that it won't send the standard form submission - only the AJAX request. As I stated in the comments on your question, you can do one or the other, but not both.

Comment: Yes, I used your code entirely on its own but it didn't trigger anything...though, as I stated, without the `fn` inside the submit it triggered entirely of its own accord. What I'm saying doesn't add up, I know, but does it make sense to you the problem I'm trying to describe?